# Node.js + Twitter Streaming memory leak

Tags: node.js, twitter, socket.io

The following is run as a service by PM2 on an Ubuntu machine. The memory footprint rises steadily from 40MB to 95MB at which point the server stops emitting but does not crash the PM2 process. This leads the webpage being unresponsive.

This code simply sends a socket emit whenever it receives a Tweet. It doesn't event emit when nobody is connected but memory usage still increases, so it's probably unrelated to SocketIO.

Just wondering what in the client.stream might be causing this leak. I installed memwatch but nothing came up.

```
var express = require('express');
var Twitter = require('twitter');
var login = require('./credentials');

var connections = 0;
var app = express();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.use(express.static('public'));

String.prototype.startsWith = function(str){
    return this.indexOf(str) === 0;
};

var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: login.creds['consumer_key'],
    consumer_secret: login.creds['consumer_secret'],
    access_token_key: login.creds['access_token_key'],
    access_token_secret: login.creds['access_token_secret']
})

client.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'drake'}, function(stream) {
    stream.on('data', function(tweet) {
        var imageUrl = undefined;
        try {
            imageUrl = tweet.entities.media[0].media_url;
        }
        catch(err) {
            // Ignored
        }
        abridgedTweet = {'text': tweet.text, 'author': tweet.user.screen_name, 'picture': imageUrl};
        if (connections > 0 && !(tweet.text.startsWith("RT")) && !(tweet.text.startsWith("@")) && tweet.lang == "en") {
            io.emit('tweet', abridgedTweet);
        };
    });
    stream.on('error', function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    })
});

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('A user connected');
    connections += 1;
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log("A user disconnected");
        connections -= 1;
        console.log(connections + " users remaining");
    });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000, pid: ' + process.pid);
});
```

Edit: I removed everything from the stream.on('data') block and memory usage is still increasing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem that people ask about when they start using PM2 and are able to clearly see memory usage. Node.js uses Google's V8 JavaScript engine, which implements the garbage collector. The GC algorithm that the V8 uses, will attempt to take up as much memory as it can, and is very lazy when it comes to cleaning up unused memory. As such, it is typical that Node processes will continue increasing in memory usage until a certain point where the GC thinks its better to free memory. Note that Node processes have a hard memory limit of 1.4 GB.

There is a way to force the GC to free up memory, using the `--expose-gc` flag. Run your server as such:

```
node --expose-gc yourscript.js
```

And append the following loop somewhere in your application. This will force garbage collection every 30 seconds.

```
setInterval(function(){
  global.gc();
  console.log('GC done')
}, 1000*30);
```

If you're using PM2, you'll need to do additional work to pass the `--expose-gc` flag in. Note that in practice you probably should just avoid doing manual garbage collection, and just let V8 do its job.

Secondly, the reason why your process is increasing in the first place despite apparently not doing anything, is likely PM2 itself. PM2 by default runs in cluster mode, as opposed to fork mode. Cluster mode will run some processes in the background, hence increasing memory over time. This memory will eventually be deallocated by the GC at some point. If you run PM2 instead in fork mode, your memory footprint should stay at the same level when the process is idle.